# Seleccionar listas no vacias de una serie de Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Luego de utilizar regex para buscar la palabra "metros" (junto a los números asociados) en la columna description de mi dataset,

```
d = dataset.description.apply(lambda x: re.findall((\d+,?\d+\s*)metros), str(x))
```

Obtengo una serie de Pandas con todas las apariciones por fila de esta palabra

[image: Serie de pandas con las apariciones del Regex]

¿Como puedo hacer para que solo se me muestren por pantalla aquellas filas en donde si haya encontrado la palabra?

Aclaración: Si encuentra resultados solo que, a la hora de imprimirlo, casualmente muestra lugares donde no encontro.

(Ejemplo: Lugares donde si encuentra)

[image: Serie de pandas donde si encuentra resultado]

He probado con:

- `for x in d: if x != []: print(x)`
- `d.loc[d != []]`

El for me ha resultado pero no me parece lo mas eficiente. El loc no me ha funcionado

Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

lista = [[], [1514], [], [23, 5]]
d = pd.Series(lista)
```

Comment: Que haz intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Ya agregue lo que intente y un ejemplo minimo verificable. Disculpen, no lo agregue antes porque me parecian intentos que no sumaban.

Comment: Ah, creo que entendí mal la pregunta, ¿Lo que deseas es encontrar todas las filas donde existe la palabra `metros` y aparte aplicar un `regex` para obtener únicamente los valores numéricos?

Comment: En este sitio, los intentos son importantes. Si bien no aportan información a la pregunta, demuestran que algo hiciste y que no sos un vago que busca que le hagan el trabajo asi nomás.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Tengo un dataset donde cada fila tiene una columna llamada "description". Para cada fila, en la columna description, quiero buscar con un regex la palabra metros junto a los números que esta traiga. Eso lo logre hacer, el problema radica a la hora de imprimir unicamente los resultados donde se encontro algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota: Como no diste datos de ejemplo, hice un dataframe con letras y numeros y una regex simple que detecta un numero.
El código usado para crear el dataframe es así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3", "4", "a", "b", "c"])
```

---

Tu código puede mejorarse. Para empezar, el uso de apply es innecesario. Pandas ya ofrece formas de cambiar el tipo de una columna y aplicarle un regex.

Por lo que tu código actual puede convertirse en:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3", "4", "a", "b", "c"])

df["found"] = df[0].astype(str).str.findall("\d")
```

Ahora, enfocandonos en la incognita que nos presentas, recuerda que en realidad se trata de listas de Python comunes y corrientes, y una lista vacía devuelve False cuando se convierte en un booleano. Por lo que podemos usar `astype(bool)` para crear una serie de booleanos, la cual simplemente podemos usar para filtrar el Dataframe. Pandas se encargará de quedarse solamente con las filas que devolvieron verdadero (o sea, que la lista tiene contenido):

```
df = df[df["found"].astype(bool)]
```

###### Código

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3", "4", "a", "b", "c"])


df["found"] = df[0].astype(str).str.findall("\d")

print(df)
print()
df = df[df["found"].astype(bool)]
print(df)
```

###### Produce

```
   0 found
0  1   [1]
1  2   [2]
2  3   [3]
3  4   [4]
4  a    []
5  b    []
6  c    []

   0 found
0  1   [1]
1  2   [2]
2  3   [3]
3  4   [4]
```

Comment: Gracias! Me ha funcionado. ¿Podrias explicarme que es lo que quieren decir los True y False a la hora de aplicar `astpye(bool)`? Entiendo que al aplicar `astype` se crea una mascara booleana la cual usare  para recorrer mi serie pero, no entiendo con que criterio `astype` coloca True o False

Comment: De nada! Viste cuando hacés un condicional que dice "if(lista)"? Es eso mismo, bool convierte las listas en booleanos, y si la lista está vacía devuelve False y si tiene elementos devuelve True. Esto no es propio de Pandas, es una caracteristica de Python en general. Es el equivalente a aplicar la función [bool](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#bool) a cada item del DataFrame.

Comment: Por cierto, si mi respuesta te sirvió te agradecería que la aceptes en forma de apoyo nwn

Comment: Esta bien, ya la coloque como respuesta destacada. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Gracias! Y de nada, es un placer ayudar c:

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay una forma más fácil de hacerlo al utilizar [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) y [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Como no agregaste tus datos hice un `dataset` de prueba en el archivo "sample2.csv" de la siguiente forma:

```
    description
0   50 metros
1   30 metros
2   aquí no hay
3   algo y 20 metros
4   aquí tampoco
5   estos son 10 metros
6   12 metros
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
print(df['description'].str.extract('(\d+,?\d+\s*)metros', expand=True).dropna())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
     0
0  50 
1  30 
3  20 
5  10 
6  12
```

Comment: Ya lo arreglé, lo había entendido mal xD

Comment: Extract es util cuando solo querés capturar un solo caso. Pero si aparecen 2 o más casos, extract se queda con el primero. Aun así es posible que al OP le sirva.

Comment: Cierto, como no hay datos no sé si en una misma línea aparezcan más números, es probable que sí por el ejemplo de la imagen final

Comment: @DanteS. estuve pensando otra opción directa pero tienes razón, `findall` sería lo mejor, otras opciones con apply y/o ciclos no serían optimas, te has ganado mi voto jaja. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias HeytalePazguato! Igual muy bien por el esfuerzo puesto en la respuesta c:

Comment: Si, puede darse el caso donde por cada fila haya mas de un dato.  Al probar con `contains` me muestra el error: `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`. No he entendido del todo bien `contains` pero, por lo que he leído, es mejor un `findall`. Muchas gracias!